# Python - egg cache extraction error - permission denied - Apache not seeing SetEnv?

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, redhat, setuptools

I'm trying to set up Apache with mod_wsgi to run Django on a Red Hat box but I'm getting the dreaded "Permission denied: '/home/pineg/.python-eggs'" egg cache extraction error.

I did what it said and made this the first line:

```
SetEnv PYTHON_EGG_CACHE /opt/tmp
```

in */etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf*

And restarted Apache:

```
>sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

But I'm still getting the same error (below).  It's almost like Apache is ignoring my SetEnv.

```
[Fri May 06 10:08:37 2011] [error] [client 10.101.11.561] The following error occurred while trying to extract file(s) to the Python egg
[Fri May 06 10:08:37 2011] [error] [client 10.101.11.561] cache:
[Fri May 06 10:08:37 2011] [error] [client 10.101.11.561] 
[Fri May 06 10:08:37 2011] [error] [client 10.101.11.561]   [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/pineg/.python-eggs'
[Fri May 06 10:08:37 2011] [error] [client 10.101.11.561] 
[Fri May 06 10:08:37 2011] [error] [client 10.101.11.561] The Python egg cache directory is currently set to:
[Fri May 06 10:08:37 2011] [error] [client 10.101.11.561] 
[Fri May 06 10:08:37 2011] [error] [client 10.101.11.561]   /home/pineg/.python-eggs
[Fri May 06 10:08:37 2011] [error] [client 10.101.11.561] 
[Fri May 06 10:08:37 2011] [error] [client 10.101.11.561] Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  You can
[Fri May 06 10:08:37 2011] [error] [client 10.101.11.561] change the cache directory by setting the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment
[Fri May 06 10:08:37 2011] [error] [client 10.101.11.561] variable to point to an accessible directory.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue and the solution is described in mod_wsgi documentation at:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Access_Rights_Of_Apache_User

Answer (score 2):

I now nothing about Apache-Django specifics, but in general

`SetEnv PYTHON_EGG_CACHE /opt/tmp`

does not set environment variable, it only add it to `environ` dict, which `application(environ, start_response)` function in `index.wsgi` should accept.

Answer (score 0):

Oh well, instead of fooling with that, I told Python to not install it as a stupid egg:

```
>sudo python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --record=/opt/python/source/weird_egg_thing
```